# on cassandra Cluster getting error : *schema does not yet agree *, when creating keyspace

Tags: schema, cassandra, cluster-computing

I am getting error *schema does not yet agree* while creating new key-space on cluster of three nodes.
have tried restarting cluster but still getting the same error
m using cassandra 0.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Covered by http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#schema_disagreement.

Short version: you need to upgrade to 0.7.8, then you need to follow the instructions at the above link to force the node with the inconsistent schema to rebuild it from one of the others.